# Reusing custom JavaFX component as JavaBean

Tags: java, javafx, javabeans

I have an exercise to do for my class which would imitate the `Spaceteam` mobile game (but this will be on the desktop). I would do one app for the captain, one for the server (communication via RMI) and multiple apps for crew members. My teacher told us to make a JavaBean (and export it as `.jar` + `BeanInfo`) which would look like this:

I have some Panel with f.e a `TextField`, a `Slider` and lets say two `RadioButtons`. So it will be one JavaBean, which I would use in three separate crew member apps, meaning the first crew member will for example have to do something with `TextField` like "enter a required (from captain) number and press the send button". And the `Slider` and `RadioButtons` will be grayed out (disabled, I mean) for him. The second one would use only the `Slider` and so on.

So the question is: Normally I would declare those 3 controls in `.fxml` file, make a Controller and run it by loading `.fxml` with `FMXLoader` in `Main`. But how can I make this kind of work to save it/produce it as a JavaBean and use in other JavaFX app (like just place it on `AnchorPane` or something)?

Comment: [BeanInfo](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/beans/BeanInfo.html) is unlikely what you want, that was a class mainly targeted to create visual design tools for Java UIs when Java was young, it is pretty much never used anymore.  At least if that is the BeanInfo which is meant here, which isn't really clear.

Comment: As a general guide, you need a way to store the state of the system (a model class in an MVC architecture), a way to marshal the data and send it over the network (looks like you are using RMI, which I think is based on serializable and hence the model should not use JavaFX properties, which are not serializable) and a way to load the model into a newly created FXML view via a controller.  Providing code for the full extent of such a system would be outside the scope of a standard StackOverflow answer.

Comment: I think the question is probably a little too broad.  Perhaps if you make it more specific, break it down into a number of different question asked separately, and include [the code which you are using which is specific to each question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (even if it is failing), it might be a bit easier to answer that way.

Comment: Study the [makery JavaFX tutorial](http://code.makery.ch/library/javafx-8-tutorial/part1/) and see how they define model classes for their views.  In that tutorial, they [marshal the objects as XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marshalling_(computer_science)), which is an alternative to [Java serialization](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/serial-137074.html).